# Missing labels in prometheus alerts

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, cadvisor

I'm having issues with Prometheus alerting rules. I have various cAdvisor specific alerts set up, for example:

```
- alert: ContainerCpuUsage
  expr: (sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[3m])) BY (instance, name) * 100) > 80
  for: 2m
  labels:
    severity: warning
  annotations:
    title: 'Container CPU usage (instance {{ $labels.instance }})'
    description: 'Container CPU usage is above 80%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}'
```

When the condition is met, I can see the alert in the "Alerts" tab in Prometheus, however some labels are missing thus not allowing alertmanager to send a notification via Slack. To be specific, I attach custom "env" label to each target:

```
 {
  "targets": [
   "localhost:8080",
  ],
  "labels": {
   "job": "cadvisor",
   "env": "production",
   "__metrics_path__": "/metrics"
  }
 }
```

But when the alert based on cadvisor metrics is firing, the labels are: alertname, instance and severity - no job label, no env label.
All the other alerts from other exporters (f.e. node-exporter) work just fine and the label is present.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to the `sum` function that you use; it gathered all the time series present and added them together, groping `BY (instance, name)`. If you run the same query in Prometheus, you will see that `sum` left only grouping labels:

```
{instance="foo", name="bar"}    135.38819037447163
```

Other aggregation methods like `avg`, `max`, `min`, etc, work in the same fashion. To bring the label back simply add `env` to the grouping list: `by (instance, name, env)`.

Comment: Thanks! I've modified my query to this:
`(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name!=""}[3m])) BY (instance, name,env) * 100) > 80` and it looks like it's working fine. Is this query okay? To be honest, I do not fully understand this: "But this way you'll get CPU utilisation per instance per name per environment." - why is that an issue?

Comment: Suppose you have a container with `env=prod` and another one with `env=dev` both on a single machine (instance). By running the query you'll get a distinct CPU utilisation for `env=dev` and `env=prod`. Since you made it so that only `env=prod` can trigger an alert, you won't get notified in case `env=dev` took all CPU resources on the machine. In other words, machine CPU Utilisation will be split between various `env` label values. Whether this is a problem depends on how things run in your environment, if there can be no other `env` except `prod` on production machines, then this is okay.

Comment: oh an one more thing @anemyte, this env label is attached to the specific target (which is cadvisor) and not to the containers themselves. It would become a problem if I ran two cadvisor containers, with different env label values. At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: @dywan666 if it's explicitly defined in job configuration for production instances, then I suppose it should be fine.